# Get web image url from real path

Tags: uri

As part of some other functionality I am generating an image in temp folder and But unforunately I'm not able get the web url of image.

```
$path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://");
$image_path = $path . rand() . '.png';
echo $image_path;
```

I am getting following as path

```
C:\wamp\www\www_d8test1_com\sites\default\files30605.png
```

How can I add slash before image name and get actual weburl of image like below?

```
http://www.d8test1.com/sites/default/files/30605.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `file_create_url()` function that creates a URL for your file.

So, based on the code in your question, it would look like:

```
// Generate or get the image uri.
$image_uri = file_default_scheme() . "://";
// Create the url from the uri.
$image_path = file_create_url($image_uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following explained [here](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/47/create-a-file-drupal-8):

```
$handle = fopen('<path to local file>', 'r');
$file = file_save_data($handle, file_default_scheme() . '<filename>');
fclose($handle);
```

and then try:

```
file_create_url(file_default_scheme() . '<filename>');
```

Comment: Drupal can deliver other files too, but this is exactly what the code in OP needs, default_scheme() is public:// by default, no reason to call realpath()   and then file_create_url() willl work nicely, no idea why this was downvoted

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @Berdir maybe you can provide an answer or edit my  answer how to deliver files outside of a file scheme. Is it possible to deliver files from scheme temporary:// ?